# Regex.IsMatch doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, regex

I want that the code:   `Regex.IsMatch(val.ToString(),"[{()}]")` will return true each time the value is a Brackets of those kinds. the code does work on those Brackets - {()} but not on those - [] .

why is that and how can I fix it? also - when I try to fix it and to reposition the Brackets  like this "{([])}" it threw me an exception - why is the Brackets   position matters and how does it effect the code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[...]` matches against a set of characters, but doesn't include `[]` since they are part of the syntax. What you want is:

```
Regex.IsMatch(val.ToString(),@"[\[{()}\]]")
```

Since it also includes `[` and `]` (escaped)

(To be clear: the above syntax matches a string that contains *any* of those characters. It doesn't make sure it includes the appropriate opening/closing character)

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by a simpler (and faster, if that matters) approach than regular expression.

Hard-coded range of characters:

```
switch (val.ToString()) {
    case "{":
    case "}":
    case "(":
    case ")":
    case "[":
    case "]":
        // match!
        break;
}
```

configurable range of characters:

```
var chars = "[]{}()".ToCharArray();
var str = val.ToString();

if (str.Length == 1 && str.IndexOfAny(chars) == 0) {
    // match!
}
```

[MSDN: `String.IndexOfAny` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexofany(v=vs.110).aspx)